# It is possible to provide multiple route params to a single component using Nuxt 3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm using Nuxt 3 to develop an e-commerce web app. For the product comparison page, I want to have a dynamic route that gets the productIds as route params. Here's the example:

domain.com/compare/[productId1]/[productId2]/[productId3]/[productId4]

Based on the official Nuxt 3 documentation, you can define a single route parameter and thus have to define the rest of the paramteres via query strings. Is there a way to provide multiple route params to a single component?

Comment: Sure, there is - simply use nested folders like `pages/compare/_id1/_id2/_id3/_id4`. However, a URL structure like this implies that these are parts, subparts and sub-subparts of a given product - not that the user is comparing from 1 up to 4 different products. For the latter you'd better stick to query parameters because they are a true `set` while route parameters can not be skipped - i.e. you can't have a URL like domain.com/compare/1///4 with missing id2 and/or id3.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Thank you for your explanation. I see your point now, and I've decided to stick to query params. 